# mysql select with while loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I would like to select data from my table and using one of the columns, create a loop to define additional data.

For example:

```
'select id,related_id,name from ancestors'

id, related_id, name
1, 0, Bob
2, 1, Dave
3, 2, Susie
4, 1, Luke
5, 0, Cindy
6, 5, Sam
```

*Bob is the grandfather, Dave and Luke are his children and Susie is his granddaughter. Cindy has a child Sam.*

Now, I want to use `related_id` to figure out how many levels the ancestor tree goes down. So I want the results to be:

```
id, related_id, name, level
1, 0, Bob, 0
2, 1, Dave, 1
3, 2, Susie, 2
4, 1, Luke, 1
5, 0, Cindy, 0
6, 5, Sam, 1
```

I would like to create a query like:

```
select id,related_id,name from ancestors; 
while related_id<>0 do level=level+1; 
select related_id from ancestors where id=related_id end;
```

Loop down the tree and count which level the individual is on inside his/her tree.

---

Here's my implementation. I can't seem to use get_level. I get an error that I can't use boolean on fetchall. What's the problem?

```
   $connection->exec('
   DELIMITER $$
   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_level` $$
   CREATE FUNCTION `get_level`(VAR int(11)) RETURNS int(11) 
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN 
   DECLARE level int(11);
   DECLARE parent int(11);
   set level=0;
   set parent=(select related_id from category where id=VAR);
   while parent>0 DO
   set level=level+1;
   set parent=(select related_id from category where id=parent);
   END 
   WHILE; 
   return level;
   END$$
   DELIMITER;');

   $fetch=$connection->query('select *,get_level(id) as level from category')->fetchall(pdo::FETCH_UNIQUE|pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);
   print_r($fetch);
```

Comment: to execute from php remove (DELIMITER $$) and (DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_level` $$) from the top and ($$   DELIMITER) from end

Answer (score 0):

you can create mysql function to get record level then call it in your query.
the function input will be the record id and output the level number.
function will be like this

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getlevel` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `get_level`(Id int(11)) RETURNS int(11) 
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE levelNumber int(11); -- declare variable to record level
DECLARE parent int(11); -- declare variable to hold the parent id
set levelNumber = 0; -- set the level to zero at the begining
set parent = (select `relation_column` from `table` where `id_column` = Id); -- get parent record of then id givin to function
while parent > 0 DO  -- loop unitl parent = 0 or record has no parent
set levelNumber = levelNumber + 1; -- increase level by 1
set parent = (select `relation_column` from `table` where `id_column` = parent); -- re set parent id
END 
WHILE; 
return levelNumber; -- return then level number
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

the relation_column is the column that hold record relation.
the id_column is the column that hold the record id or (primary key).

final query will be like this

```
select `table`.`id_column`,`table`.`relation_column`,`table`.`name`,get_level(`table`.`id_column`) as  "level" from `table`
```

hope this would help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added my implementation. I keep getting an error.