# MySQL create a stored procedure that loops itself

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to create a mysql function that can find all related ancestors using column `related` in the table `category` and then use all those ancestors (children, grandchildren...) ids including itself to find all instances of those ids in `listing_category` using column `category`.

**category**

```
ID, Related
1,0
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,0
6,5
7,1
8,7
9,7
10,1
```

*If I pick 1 then 2,3,4,7,10 are its children and 8,9 are its grandchildren.*

**listing_category**

```
Category
1
1
2
3
3
5
6
9
7
7
```

So now I want to create a MySql function that can count all instances of 1,2,3,4,7,10,8,9 in another table called `listing_category`

```
   create function listing_count(ID int(11)) returns int(11)
   begin 
    declare count int(11);
    set count=(select count(*) from listing_category where category=ID);
    while (select id from category where related=ID) as childID and count<100 do
     set count=count+listing_count(childID);
    end while;
    return count; 
   end
```

So `listing_count(1)` will find all relatives 2,3,4,7,10,8,9 inside `category` and then count all instances of 1,2,3,4,7,10,8,9 inside `listing_category`. So a count of 8 would be returned in this example.

Possible with mysql stored procedures?

Comment: Try to join the table with itself using the relationship and do the count. If you need parent -> children -> grandchildren, you need to join the table twice.

Comment: Your return value of `9` doesn't seem correct. Shouldn't it be `8`?

Comment: @clinomaniac yes you are correct. 8 is the answer

Comment: Is it possible to declare an array and us that array in an 'select in' statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive stored procedure. This has the advantage that it works regardless of the depth of ancestors e.g. children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren etc.

```
delimiter //
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS listing_count //
create procedure listing_count(in parentID int(11), out thesum int(11))
begin 
  declare childID int(11);
  declare childSum int(11);
  declare finished int default 0;
  declare childID_cursor cursor for select id from category where related=parentID;
  declare continue handler for not found set finished = 1;
  select count(*) into thesum from listing_category where category=parentID;
  open childID_cursor;
  get_children: LOOP
    fetch childID_cursor into childID;
    if finished = 1 then 
      LEAVE get_children;
    end if;
    call listing_count(childID, childSum);
    set thesum = thesum + childSum;
  end loop get_children;
  close childID_cursor;
end
//
```

With your data, this query yields the expected result (8):

```
SET @@SESSION.max_sp_recursion_depth=25;
call listing_count(1, @x);
select @x;
```

If you really want a function you can wrap the procedure inside one (since MySQL won't let you create recursive functions):

```
DELIMITER //
drop function if exists lc//
create function lc(id int(11)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  declare sum int(11);
  call listing_count(id, sum);
  return sum;
END
//
select lc(1)
```

Output:

```
8
```

Comment: Hi Maciek, did this work for you? It could probably be easily adapted to answer your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999126/mysql-select-with-while-loop) too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the related categories in one column, you need to UNION all the IDs from l1 (just one row), l2 and l3.

```
SELECT l1.* FROM category l1
WHERE l1.id = ID
UNION ALL
SELECT l2.* FROM category l1
    INNER JOIN category l2 ON l1.related = l2.id
WHERE l1.id = ID
UNION ALL
SELECT l3.* FROM category l1
    INNER JOIN category l2 ON l1.related = l2.id
    INNER JOIN category l3 ON l2.related = l3.id
WHERE l1.id = ID
```

Once you have all the IDs you can get the count:

Here is a query that will count the records for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listing_category 
WHERE category IN (
SELECT l1.* FROM category l1
    WHERE l1.id = ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l2.* FROM category l1
        INNER JOIN category l2 ON l1.related = l2.id
    WHERE l1.id = ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l3.* FROM category l1
        INNER JOIN category l2 ON l1.related = l2.id
        INNER JOIN category l3 ON l2.related = l3.id
    WHERE l1.id = ID)
```